# Add multiple fragments programmatically to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-relativelayout

I want to construct a View that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PoSa.png), where Fragment2's height should wrap its content and Fragtment1 should fill the remaining space above.

After reading up for ways to do that I got the following layout.xml for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.jamest.textadventuretest.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.jamest.textadventuretest.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/fragment2" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.jamest.textadventuretest.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and it works.
Now I want to do the same, but programmatically, so that I can replace/add these two fragments (simultaneously) with another fragment.

I commented out both fragment-blocks in the layout.xml and added the following to the onCreate()-method of my activity:

```
fragment2 = new Fragment2();
fragment1 = new Fragment1();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2)
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
```

Now I have to set the layout_above and layout_alignParentBottom parameters so that it displays correctly.

First, I tried to set these parameters to the view by calling fragment1.getView() after committing, but I get a NullPointerException.
After reading up I understand, that I can access the view only after the onCreateView() method of the fragment is called, and that is not the case immediately after commit() is called. Even if it is followed by

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()
```

So I created an Interface in the fragments where a method is called after the view has been created (in onActivityCreated()) and the activity implements these interfaces.

The implemented methods look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreatedFragment1() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.layout.fragment2);
    fragment1.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCreatedFragment2() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,1);
    fragment2.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

but still, I can only see Fragment1 that is on top of Fragment2...
If I comment out Fragment1, I can see that Fragment2 is aligned on the bottom.

What is the best way to solve that problem?

I think I can add two seperate containers in the layout.xml of the activity, but I want to replace back and forth both fragments with a bigger one in the application.
Should I leave the second container empty then?
Or is there a better way to go about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think by your code, you are creating fragment1 first then creating fragment2, just go with creating fragment2 first then fragment1(Because above condition should be work in this case only).

Comment: And why you are replacing fragment to same "R.id.fragment_container", i think you are replacing same fragment container for both fragment.

Comment: oh, that was a mistake (I changed the fragment's name for the code snippets), I did that! edited

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting this point, will you please check this code:

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2)
.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
```

Why you are adding both fragment on same 'fragment_container'.

**EDITED:**

```
   RelativeLayout topLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content1);





    FrameLayout frameLayout2 = new FrameLayout(this);

    frameLayout2.setId(101);
    frameLayout2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    frameLayout2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


    topLayout.addView(frameLayout2);




   FrameLayout frameLayout1 = new FrameLayout(this);
    frameLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,frameLayout2.getId());
    frameLayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


    topLayout.addView(frameLayout1);
```

Now do your code for Fragments as:

```
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(frameLayout2, fragment2)
    .add(frameLayout1, fragment1).commit();
```

Here,topLayout is parent layout.
hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: because I only want one container to hold both fragments, so it looks like the example xml I gave.
Or is that not a good way to do things?

Comment: your edited code?
I don't know what you mean...

the first fragment does not replace the second one - if I use an explicit height for the first fragment I can see both of them!

Comment: Hey find code, i edited it with correct one. Use this code it surely work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I figured as much, but I am hesitant to use this approach, because now I have to keep track and remove those two FrameLayouts if I want to switch those two fragments with another one, whereas I only have to replace the first fragment with a bigger one and remove the second one with the initial approach.

Any idea why I doens't work like I tried to do it?

If there are no more answers I will accept yours!

Comment: James thankyou soo much for appreciation, but sorry Brother i don't think there is another solution for doing this. Because you need always two framelayout for showing two fragments, and you have to manage with that. Sorry i understand your situation.

Comment: Hey james, atleast upvote my answer. it will make me happy.

Comment: I did upvote, but I have too little reputation for it to be shown publicly!

I found a solution to achieve what I wanted and added an answer.

Comment: Ok no problem. may i able to satisfy your need?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got what I want to achieve, although it seems all a bit cumbersome.

I simply changed

```
@Override
public void onCreatedFragment1() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.layout.fragment2);
    fragment1.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onCreatedFragment1() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, fragment2.getView().getId();
    fragment1.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

I have to be sure that fragment2's view is created before fragment1 or else I get a NullPointerException.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I want without defining multiple FrameLayouts in my main activity beforehand?

Comment: For what reason do you want only one container? It is a better practice to have 1 container per fragment.

Comment: Only because for the most part there is only one fragment displayed. Is it better to replace the first fragment in its container and remove the second, leaving its container empty?

Comment: Okay I reread your question so I understand what you mean now. What I would do is have the two FrameLayouts in the Relative layout as you have, and then then have the RelativeLayout nested in a FrameLayout. You can replace the contents of the outermost FrameLayout with your third Fragment or with the RelativeLayout that contains both your smaller fragments. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand, so like [this](https://i.imgur.com/HeaFxHM.png)?
But how would I switch back via FragmentManager? Or would I keep a copy of the populated RelativeLayout in memory? Sorry if these are dumb questions, it is my first project and I try to manage the different "screens" via fragments like it is recommend by the guidelines.

Comment: Your picture looks accurate. As for keep the layout in memory, it depends on the data that you have in those fragments if you need to keep it in memory. Would the data need to be reloaded from somewhere (like an internet server or something)? Do they need to remember user choices or preferences? In those cases you'd likely want to keep the fragments around. The easiest way would be just to change the z position of the relative layout. Otherwise if all the data is static and/or quick to load, you can swap out the layouts.

Comment: Also as a side note, my preference is to do as much with XML as possible. I find it cleaner. Others might disagree, but the using XML allows you to easily preview what all of the static data will look like. It's still code unlike the UI Builder, but it's entire purpose is to define your views. You can define everything like you did in your XML in the question, and then inflate the view and manipulate it like you do programmatically. I still recommend keeping the FrameLayout around the fragment, but it's up to you in the end.